# ros on rapsberry pi

Tags: raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hai.. im new to ros..im searching for a os for my  project.
can we use ros in rapsberry pi??
i want to make a robotic vehicle that can controlled by touch screen is it possible with ros??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52321/ros-on-rapsberry-pi/) by [viki](https://answers.ros.org/users/3971/viki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [viki](https://answers.ros.org/users/3971/viki/) on 2013-01-16**:
so i need a pc to run my robot..what if i use some intel mother board with intel atom or pentium, linux runing on it  to control the robot is it possible?? suggest me some controller ?? instead of running in linux platform can i go fo rtlinux or win ce ?? will it work real time in those platform /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to install the latest release (groovy) follow the instructions [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Raspbian/Source). There is also an image for the raspi, so you can get started right away

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's actually a guide on the wiki to setting up ROS on raspbian [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROSberryPi/Setting%20up%20ROS%20on%20RaspberryPi).

EDIT: the guide is technically for fuerte on debian squeeze, but there's a raspbian part on there, too.  Also, at the time of this writing, you'll also need to use the workaround mentioned [here](https://github.com/ros/rosdep/issues/44) if you're going to use fuerte since rosdep isn't backwards compatible.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1